# lightgallery-zoom.js importing causes "property 'modules' of undefined" WP functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, lightgallery

Currently I have lightgallery which working perfectly, but when I import additional plugin to it "lg-zoom.js" I'm getting error "property 'modules' of undefined".

In the functions.php I have:

```
  wp_enqueue_script('lightgallery', get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/vendor/lightgallery.min.js", array('jquery'), WEB_VERSION, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('lg-zoom', get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/vendor/lg-zoom.min.js", array('jquery'), WEB_VERSION, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the main `lightgallery` script as a dependency to the `lg-zoom` module:

```
wp_enqueue_script('lightgallery', get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/vendor/lightgallery.min.js", array('jquery'), WEB_VERSION, false);
wp_enqueue_script('lg-zoom', get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/vendor/lg-zoom.min.js", array('jquery', 'lightgallery'), WEB_VERSION, false); // 'jquery' could be even skipped here, since lightgallery already requires it.
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but unfortunately still getting same error, should I try to use imports instead of functions.php? https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery/issues/749

Comment: It seems that lightGallery v2+ is largely different from v1. It is not using jQuery anymore. What version of lightgallery are you including? https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery/tree/2.0.0

Comment: This one https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightgallery.js

Comment: Please read https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightgallery.js#important-notice. Also see the readme on including plugins: https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery/tree/2.0.0#include-css-and-javascript-files